# How can I display a block only when a node meets a particular condition?

Tags: 6, nodes, blocks, workflows

I have a block that allows a site visitor to query an external calendar, but it will only work for certain nodes.

How can I set it up so that I can i) indicate whether or not a node has calendar data available for the node and ii) if it has calendar data available, display the block and if it hasn't got calendar data available, the block is not displayed?

Someone suggested to me that I use Workflow to do this, but I've not been able to figure out how Workflow would help me set this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the PHP visibility settings to display the block on a node's page if a cck value in that node has some value, assuming that this cck field's value is an indication of that node containing calendar data. Once you've created the block that you want to display (or not display) add the following code to the "Page specific visibility settings" in the block configuration menu:

```
<?php 
$node = node_load( arg(1) );

if ($node && $node->type =="[your_content_type]" && $node->field_has_cal_data[0]['value'] =='Yes'){
return TRUE;
}

return FALSE;

?>
```

This is assuming that the url is built like "content/name-or-id-of-node".

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense (and it would seem to be less complicated than using Workflow as a solution).

Presumably the PHP visibility settings are the ones found in the block specific settings.

Comment: Yup...the php visibility settings are in the block specific settings.

Comment: Don't use the error suppression operator (`@`). It's useless in this particular situation, because `node_load` does not output anything if the node does not exist, it returns `false` instead. Then again, accessing `$node->type` might result in a notice if the node does not exist, so that would be a better place for an error suppression operator. However, the best place for the error suppression operator is PHP's deprecated list. Use proper error checking instead: if the node does not load, return `false`, else test further conditions.

Comment: @Oswald - Made the changes per your comment. Let me know if that works or feel free to make edits to my original answer.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks! If I want it to apply to multiple content types, presumably I use an 'IF' statement there?

Comment: Ya, you can use and IF Else statement check for different content types, and if there is no content type return FALSE